# Mysql Grant with option to skip a db

Tags: mysql, mysql5

One of my db have tables around 10000(temporary use).
But what it has done that opening phpmyadmin become slow and my version is "2.6.0-pl2".

Because of this version I cannot use `skip_db` option of phpmyadmin.

So I decided to have a new user with permission to all database except one but I don't know how to do that.

So can someone tell me how to write grant to all db with skipping just one db ?

Comment: how about grant privileges to all db then delete privilege for the one you want

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a user for this problem.

use show database command and you will get list of db.

In phpmyadmin version "2.6.0-pl2" , you can use show_db variable and set all tables there are your problem will be solved